# How to quickly convert text to org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

windows 10, emacs 26.1

Supose I have the following text:

```
OwnerKey    OrganizationName    GUID
111192    Infocom    41EA23423423423423423C8-62A61A1532C5
345423   TV    A3B8F234234234234239FA5-4D71242359EE
123423     TV    A3B823423423424234-234234234322659EE
```

I need to create something like this:

```
| OwnerKey | OrganizationName | GUID                                 |
|----------+------------------+--------------------------------------|
|   111192 | Infocom          | 41EA23423423423423423C8-62A61A1532C5 |
|   345423 | TV               | A3B8F234234234234239FA5-4D71242359EE |
|   123423 | TV               | A3B823423423424234-234234234322659EE |
```

How I can do this quickly. I don't want to do this manually line by line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the data.

`M-x table-capture`

Now it will ask questions like what is the delimiter etc.

For column delimiter hit space key

Row delimiter is `RET`, but we can't use it because it's the confirmation key, so you need to hit

`C-q C-j`

Other options you can probably leave at their defaults.

Answer (score 12):

You find the `Tbl` menu at the right side of the `Org` menu.
Mark the region you want to convert to an org-table and click on the menu item `Tbl -> Convert Region`.

The result is a table without header:

```
| OwnerKey | OrganizationName | GUID                                 |
|   111192 | Infocom          | 41EA23423423423423423C8-62A61A1532C5 |
|   345423 | TV               | A3B8F234234234234239FA5-4D71242359EE |
|   123423 | TV               | A3B823423423424234-234234234322659EE |
```

Adding the missing header is easy. Place point behind the first line Press <kbd>RET</kbd> for a newline and input the two characters `|-` and a <kbd>tab</kbd>. This adjusts the underlining of the header automagically.

---

You can use the minor mode `orgtbl-mode` also in buffers that are not in `org-mode` but in other major modes like `text-mode`.
Just call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `orgtbl-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> and you get a new menu `OrgTbl` in the menu bar.
There you find the menu item `Create or Convert` bound to the key <kbd>C-|</kbd>. That works very similar to the above `Convert Region`.

It may be that you cannot insert the newline for the header underlining by just typing <kbd>RET</kbd> behind the first line.
In that case type <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> instead of <kbd>RET</kbd> to insert a newline.
Everything else works like for `Convert Region` above.

The really nice thing is that you even can insert `#+TBLFM:` lines below the table. Those lines work like in `org-mode` when you type <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on them.

Comment: This is possible only in org mode. But what about text mode?

Comment: @Alexei See my edit.

Comment: For those, like me, who deactivated the menu in their Emacs, the command is `M-x` `orgtbl-create-or-convert-from-region`

Comment: nice, this was easier, faster and produced a better result than `M-x table-capture`.

Comment: `org-table-convert-region` command works too. thanks

Answer (score 5):

While I really liked the answers here, I personally found that both `table-capture` and `orgtbl-create-or-convert-from-region` did not suit my situation well. So here's another option:

Select the text and use either <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp` for each of the following:

1. `^` -> `|`  (<kbd>|</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>)
2. -> `|` (three spaces to <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>)
3. `$` ->  `|` (<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>|</kbd>)

Finally, insert a line after the heading and type <kbd>|</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> to create a horizontal rule and align the table.