# How do I switch a .txt table to a .org table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I already have the following table in a file `elite_cyclists.txt`

```
Name                Height  Weight  BMI
Nairo Quintana      167     59      21.2
Chris Froome        186     68      19.9
Robert Förstemann   174     90      29.7
Conor Dunne         204     88      21.1
```

hand-aligned using tab characters.

I would like to store the data in a file `elite_cyclists.org` within a table in `org-mode`.

I could:

- copy the entries by hand,
- write a macro that cleverly (or not) copies from position to cell (in `C-x 2`, say), or
- insert the requisite `----`, `|`, and `+` 's to make the table a semantic table, then copy to the `.org` file.

But all these seem like hacks.

Is there a mechanism for switching a .txt table to a org table?

###### Related

- [How to quickly convert text to org-mode table?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/46353/28733)

Comment: Org mode tables do not have boxes around each cell. You might be thinking of `table.el` tables? For the alignment, see my answer.

Comment: @NickD When I specify a cell-width that's too narrow for the content of some cells, the text in those cells gets split to multiple lines. Also, as soon as I press `C-c backquote`, the org-mode editor inserts those row separators. Puzzling...

Comment: Not in any Org mode that I'm familiar with: the cell expands to accommodate the length of the field (and TAB realigns everything) and `C-c <backquote>` is bound to `org-table-edit-field`. Are you *sure* you are not talking about `table.el` tables?

Comment: See [Built-in table editor](https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html) in the Org mode manual and see [table.el tables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html) in the Emacs manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the table into an org-buffer, highlight it to set the region and do `M-x org-table-convert-region`.  That's all!

Comment: I am truly amazed. But still, I'm missing a detail. Could you look at the clarification question above?

Comment: See @NickD's answer.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I missed the `... hand-aligned by TABs...` part, and since I never use TAB characters in my files (except in Makefiles where they are significant), I misinterpreted the input. Nevertheless, the answer below might still be useful.

---

The function `org-table-convert-region` can be used to convert textual tabular material into an org table. Ideally, the textual material would have unambiguous field boundaries (e.g. commas or tabs in the case of CSV/TSV files), but the function can deal with somewhat regular ambiguous situations like the one you have: you have spaces separating the fields but you also have a single space between first and last name in the `Names` column; a quick look shows that if you can specify a separator of two or more spaces, that should be enough.

Fortunately the function *can* take a `separator` argument and as the doc string (`C-h f org-table-convert-region`) shows, you can specify a regular expression for it: `"  +"` (there are *two* spaces in there) will match two or more spaces. However, you will have to evaluate the function non-interactively to be able to specify the separator.

Start by marking the region (`C-SPC` on one end and then move `point` to the other end) and then say:

```
M-: (org-table-convert-region (region-beginning) (region-end) "  +")
```

You will also have to add the hline that separates the header line from the body of the table by hand. But that's easily done:
open a line and type `|-` followed by `TAB` to realign the table.

---

EDIT: BTW, you could deal with multiple TABs the same way as above. The separator regexp would have to be changed to `"\t+"` (i.e. one or more TABs) but that's all.

However, reformatting the original file to provide unambiguous field boundaries (e.g. a single TAB or a single comma) would make it a two-step operation as described by @FranBurstall's answer. Preprocessing the input to make it convenient for future transformations is a technique that's worth keeping in the back of your mind. And it does not have to be done in Emacs: a `sed` script can do it easily in your case, converting multiple TABs to a single one: `sed -E 's/\t+/\t/g'` (with GNU `sed`) should do it.

Comment: Here's hoping that once I learn `org-mode` I also will stop using TAB characters—other than for `Makefile`s.

Comment: No, that's my peculiarity: lots of people use TABs in their files and lead long, productive lives :-)

Answer (score 2):

##### Caution

First a word of caution. If you call `org-table-convert-region`, you may not get what you want.

```
| Name   | Height     | Weight | BMI |      |
| Nairo  | Quintana   |    167 |  59 | 21.2 |
| Chris  | Froome     |    186 |  68 | 19.9 |
| Robert | Förstemann |    174 |  90 | 29.7 |
| Conor  | Dunne      |    204 |  88 | 21.1 |
```

##### Ensure single TABs

Hence you need first to make sure that the table has one and exactly one TAB character between cells.

```
Name    Height  Weight  BMI
Nairo Quintana  167 59  21.2
Chris Froome    186 68  19.9
Robert Förstemann   174 90  29.7
Conor Dunne 204 88  21.1
```

This can be easily done by, for example, search-replacing `TAB TAB` with `TAB`, in multiple passes until it fails at the start (although there is surely a better way via `isearch-forward-regexp`).

##### Run `org-table-convert-region`

It's now sufficient to copy-paste the data to a .org file, mark the region (with or without the final end-of-line) and run `M-x org-table-convert-region`. The result will be:

```
| Name              | Height | Weight |  BMI |
| Nairo Quintana    |    167 |     59 | 21.2 |
| Chris Froome      |    186 |     68 | 19.9 |
| Robert Förstemann |    174 |     90 | 29.7 |
| Conor Dunne       |    204 |     88 | 21.1 |
```

###### Credit: Fran Burstall

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use `M-x untabify` to convert the tabs into spaces, then select the region and do `C-u 2 C-c |` to convert the table to an org-mode table.  The numerical prefix specifies that at least 2 spaces are needed to denote a new column, which will avoid breaking the names and misaligning the numerical columns.

Answer (score 1):

*This is an answer for those who enjoy using Emacs's rectangle commands.*

##### Leave multiple tabs where they are

```
Name              Height  <TAB>Weight        BMI
Nairo Quintana    167<TAB><TAB>59            21.2
Chris Froome      186  (etc)   68            19.9
Robert Förstemann 174          90            29.7
Conor Dunne       204          88            21.1
```

##### and run `string-rectangle` <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> multiple times to insert the requisite `|` marks.

```
| Name              | Height        | Weight    | BMI  | 
| Nairo Quintana    | 167           | 59        | 21.2 | 
| Chris Froome      | 186           | 68        | 19.9 | 
| Robert Förstemann | 174           | 90        | 29.7 | 
| Conor Dunne       | 204           | 88        | 21.1 |
```

This will require manually (and perhaps laboriously, YMMV) re-aligning columns as you proceed.

##### Now switch to `text-mode` and back to `org-mode`. The table will look corrupted, but it will be recognized as a table.

```
| Name                      | Height                | Weight        | BMI  | 
| Nairo Quintana    | 167                   | 59            | 21.2 | 
| Chris Froome              | 186                   | 68            | 19.9 | 
| Robert Förstemann | 174                   | 90            | 29.7 | 
| Conor Dunne               | 204                   | 88            | 21.1 |
```

##### Now simply press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in any cell to adjust the cell alignment.

```
| Name              | Height | Weight |  BMI |
| Nairo Quintana    |    167 |     59 | 21.2 |
| Chris Froome      |    186 |     68 | 19.9 |
| Robert Förstemann |    174 |     90 | 29.7 |
| Conor Dunne       |    204 |     88 | 21.1 |
```